# Comparison of standard scores vs percentile scores or categorisation. Which one is more powerful?

Tags: categorical-data, mean, standard-deviation, quantiles, z-score

I am researching on anxiety levels in a population including 80 subjects before and after an intervention that possibly might be cause to rise in anxiety levels. I wonder which method is more correct or powerful?

1. Just comparing the standard scores
2. Converting to the percentile scores and comparing
3. Categorised scores into three levels (low, moderate,high) and comparing

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more information? What is the scale on which you measure anxiety? Is there prior knowledge on the distribution of the scores or an error model?

Comment: @IgorF. I will use State-Trait Anxiety Inventory (STAI). Range of scores is  20–80, the higher score indicating greater anxiety.

Answer (score 1):

For that many subjects and that range of scores, I'd compare the raw scores, most probably using the paired t-test. Converting to percentiles, if the transformation is linear, would lead to equally valid results, but not that obvious to interpret. Categorizing the scores is, in addition, somewhat arbitrary and involves loss of information. I'd avoid it if possible.